# Django Error On updating based on DateTime From Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have been working on certain Bus schedule.

```
 class Schedule(BaseModel):
    bus_company_route = models.ForeignKey(BusCompanyRoute, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    bus = models.ForeignKey(Bus, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    travel_date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    seat_discounted_price_for_user = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        default_permissions = ()
        verbose_name = 'Schedule'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Schedules'
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=[
            'bus_company_route',
            'bus',
            'travel_date_time'
        ],
            name='unique_schedule')
        ]


    def clean(self):
         if not self.bus_company_route.shift:
            raise DjangoValidationError(
            {'bus_company_route': _('Shift does not exist in {}'.format(self.bus_company_route.route  ))})
         try:
            if self.travel_date_time:
                if Schedule.objects.filter(
                    bus_company_route=self.bus_company_route,
                    bus=self.bus,
                    travel_date_time__date=self.travel_date_time.date()
                ).exists():
                    raise DjangoValidationError({
                        'travel_date_time': _('Cannot assign same bus on same date')
                    })
         except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
```

Logic is I have made clean method to check if there exists travel date time first. Next logic is if  `bus_company_route,  bus ,travel_date_time` is on suppose Dec 24 then you cannot add same bus on the same date.The problem is when I create a Schedule & tried updating `seat_discounted_price_for_user` when date is still Dec 24 I get error saying Cannot assign same bus on same date. what can I do so that I can update `Schedule` details after adding `Schedule`.

Comment: use unique_together in class Meta, instead of clean data. when you are trying to update data then it will take older data and run your clean method logic

Comment: i have used unique constraint  for  `bus_company_route ,bus, travel_date_time`

Comment: share your views.py

Comment: there is no need of views for this I tried adding and updating from admin but on update I got error

Comment: I have updated my code with meta class

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Schedule, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.old_id = self.id
```

in def clean

```
try:
    if self.travel_date_time and self.old_id != self.id:
```

Comment: got error saying `__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 15 were given`